# JSON encode problems php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

What is wrong with the way this is encoded?

```
<?php  
include ("../includes/db_con.php");

    $itemResults = mysql_query("SELECT `sold_for` FROM `items` WHERE `item_did_sell`='1'") or die();
    $mIResults = mysql_query("SELECT `mi_price`, `mi_total_sold` FROM `misc_items` WHERE `mi_total_sold`>'1'") or die();
    $donationResults = mysql_query("SELECT `amount` FROM `donations`") or die(mysql_error());

$total = 0;
$itemTotal = 0;
$mITotal = 0;
$donationTotal = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($itemResults)){  
    $itemTotal += $row['sold_for'];
    $total += $itemTotal;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mIResults)){  
    $mITotal += ($row['mi_price'] * $row['mi_total_sold']);
    $total += $mITotal;
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($donationResults)){  
    $donationTotal += $row['amount'];
    $total += $donationTotal;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$arr = array('items' => $itemTotal,'mitems' => $mITotal,'donations' => $donationTotal,'total' => $total);
$arr =  json_encode($arr);
echo $arr;

include ("../includes/db_discon.php");
?>
```

The script outputs:
`{"items":1000,"mitems":0,"donations":0,"total":1000}`

Occurring to my client side javascript (which has been verified) there is a parase error in my json array.

Comment: What is the *output* of this script?

Comment: It outputs: `{"items":1000,"mitems":0,"donations":0,"total":1000}`

Comment: That's perfectly valid JSON that's output there, looks fine.

Comment: Either your parser is coded wrong or your client side javascript is wrong. That's completely valid json.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/